# How does a unitary operator acts on an entangled $|\psi\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, notation

If there is: 
$$
U = \sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_2} |x \dot{+} y\rangle |y\rangle \langle x| \langle y|
$$
acting over $|\psi\rangle$ which can be $|00\rangle, |01\rangle, |10\rangle, |11\rangle$, does it act on the first qubit or on both?
Also if I want to take the partial trace:
$$
Tr_{1}[U(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|U^{\dagger}]
$$
would it be correct to do:
$$
Tr_{1}[U(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|U^{\dagger}]
$$
$$
= \sum_{ n,u,w,x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_2} \langle n| x \dot{+} y\rangle \langle x | \psi\rangle\langle\psi|w\rangle\langle w\dot{+} z|n\rangle  |x \dot{+} y\rangle \langle x | \psi\rangle\langle\psi|w\rangle\langle w\dot{+} z|
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the partial trace of this subsystem equal to this?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/416233/)

Comment: Please do not ask minor variations of the same question over and over again - all your five questions on this site are essentially "How do I take the partial trace?" Please be *more specific* as to what you do not understand about the partial trace and *edit* your question instead of posting it anew.

Answer (score 0):

Your unitary looks like a controlled-X from the second to the first qubit. It is fairly easy to work through what it does by just plugging in definitions.

$U = |00\rangle\langle 00| + |11\rangle\langle 01| + |10\rangle\langle10| + |01\rangle\langle11|$

So in answer to your question it does act on both. In fact it takes the computational basis to the maximally entangled state.

For your second question the definitions are correct and plugging in is the correct approach.

$Tr(U |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|  U^\dagger) = \sum_{m,m',n,x,y,x',y'} |m\rangle\langle n,m| |x\oplus y, y\rangle\langle x, y| \psi\rangle\langle \psi|x',y'\rangle\langle x' \oplus y', y'| |n,m'\rangle\langle m'|$

I have made the notational change $|x\rangle|y\rangle = |x,y\rangle$ to avoid confusion since $|\psi\rangle$ is a two qubit state and so $\langle\psi|x\rangle|y\rangle$ would mistakenly imply the inner product  $\langle\psi|x\rangle$. The outer most $|m\rangle , \langle m' |$ is only one qubit since the other is traced away.

clearly we only get non-zero terms when $n = x \oplus y$ and $y = m$ and likewise for the primed variables. Thus we get

$Tr(U |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|  U^\dagger) = \sum_{m,m',n} |m\rangle\langle n \oplus m, m| \psi\rangle\langle \psi|n \oplus m', m'\rangle\langle m'|$

Which really isn't the same as what you wrote. Unless you intended $\psi$ to be a single qubit state? If so which qubit?